Unable to connect to SapBusinessWarehouse from Power bi
When Iam trying to connect to SAp data warehouse it gives me this error the other users can connect but iam only can edit existing query or refreesh but can't add new query
Details: "SAP Business Warehouse: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Microsoft.Mashup.SapBwProvider.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.Mashup.SapBwProvider31" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."
Iam try to connect to SAP Warehouse data
